# How to make an Objective-C class conform to a protocol defined in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

I have a class written in Swift where I've defined a protocol:

```
protocol PhotoIngestionDelegate {
    func pictureTaken()
}
```

I am trying to have a class (CameraViewController) written in Objective-C conform to this protocol.

CameraViewController.h:

```
#import <GSSDK/GSSDK.h>

@protocol PhotoIngestionDelegate;

@interface CameraViewController : GSKCameraViewController <PhotoIngestionDelegate>

@end
```

CameraViewController.m:

```
#import "CameraViewController.h"

#import <GSSDK/GSSDK.h>
#import "EditFrameViewController.h"
#import "Scan.h"


@interface CameraViewController<PhotoIngestionDelegate> ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *toolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *cameraButton;

@end

@implementation CameraViewController

...
```

The implementation in CameraViewController.m continues, but I cut it off to keep it brief. I know that I need to define the function pictureTaken() in CameraViewController.m, but I can't seem to get the delegate hookup to work. In CameraViewController.h I am getting that it `Cannot find protocol definition for 'PhotoIngestionDelegate'`.

Comment: At glance, make it conform to NSObjectProtocol via inheritance

Comment: @StephenJ how would that look?

Comment: @jordan U got ur solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@objc protocol PhotoIngestionDelegate {

}
```